# How to display queryset list?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am creating website for game tournaments. I have specialized queryset. I want to display on one page teams' names and their players.

I tried to work with "get_queryset()" function but I don't understand what exactly. Probably there is mistake in template section.

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class TestTeam(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='Team')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=5)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class TestPlayer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='Player')
    nick = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='Nickname')
    team = models.ForeignKey(TestTeam, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, default='Team')
    #photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='', null=True)
    No = 'N'
    Yes = 'Y'
    STANDIN_CHOICES = [
        (Yes, 'Yes'),
        (No, 'No'),
    ]
    standin = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=STANDIN_CHOICES, default=No)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=20, default=nick)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class TestMatch(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='Match')
    leftTeam = models.ForeignKey(TestTeam, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='+', default='Left Team')
    rightTeam = models.ForeignKey(TestTeam, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='+', default='Right Team')
    slug = models.SlugField(default=str(name))

    def __str__(self):
        return (str(self.leftTeam) +" - "+ str(self.rightTeam))
```

urls.py

```
from . import views
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.TestView.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('<slug:slug>/', views.MatchView.as_view(), name='match'),
]
```

views.py

```
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from . import models
from django.shortcuts import get_list_or_404

class TestView(ListView):
    model = models.TestMatch
    template_name = 'home.html'

class MatchView(DetailView):
    model = models.TestPlayer
    template_name = 'match.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        if 'slug' in self.kwargs:
            team_slug = self.kwargs['slug']
            TEAM = get_list_or_404(models.TestTeam, slug=team_slug)
            queryset = queryset.filter(team=TEAM[0])
        return queryset
```

HTML for displaying(match.html)

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}

{% regroup  object_list by team as player_list %}
    {% for player in player_list %}
        <h3>{{ player.name }}</h3>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

I want Teams and their players to be displayed on one page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [**`{% regroup .. %}`** tag [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup) means that `player_list` contains not a list of `player`s: it contains groups of teams, and in each group there is a list of players.

You thus render this as:

```
{% regroup object_list by team as team_list %}
{% for team in team_list %}
    <h3>{{ team.grouper }}</h4>
    {% for player in team.list %}
        <h4>{{ player }}</h4>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Here the `grouper` is thus a reference to the `Team`, and the `team.list` will then contain an iterable of related `Player`s.

Comment: Thanks for help, but what is team.list. In the first string team_list was declared, but not team.list.

Comment: @KochetovMXM: team is here a "group" this is basically what you constructed with the `regroup`: a group has two attributes `grouper`: the item on which you grouped, and `.list`: the items of the original list that are in that group.

Comment: The next problem appeared... I have url-path to the teams' page by <slug:slug>. You can see it in "urls.py" file. When I am inserting ""http://127.0.0.1:8000/navi/"" to my adress string. It gives back 404, like there are no players in team with slug "navi", but there are.

Comment: @KochetovMXM: based on the current logic, your slug does not do anything and is empty. The `TestMatch` slug will even just have `<CharField(...)` at ..>` as default value. I suggest using an `AutoSlugField` instead, such that you can define the `populate_from` parameter: https://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/field_extensions.html

Comment: One more question, in my queryset filter I have (team=TEAM[0]). As I understand, it will give me players only from the one team, but I have 2 teams in one match. How can I return a list to a queryset?

Comment: @KochetovMXM: if you have the two teams, you can filter with `.filter(team__in=[team1, team2])`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Can I get any of your social media links, please?

Comment: @KochetovMXM: I don't use social media :)

Answer (score 0):

instead of this:

```
TEAM = get_list_or_404(models.TestTeam, slug=team_slug)
queryset = queryset.filter(team=TEAM[0])
```

try this:

```
queryset = queryset.filter(team__slug=team_slug)
```